# /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should

Tags: partitioning, gparted, gpt

When I open gparted, I get the following warning:

> /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
>   However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should. Perhaps it was corrupted—possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables. Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?

This is on a SSD if it makes any difference.

What is this and how do I fix it?